# List of Objects and Id not getting passed to MVC Controller Method Using jQuery Ajax

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Im trying to pass an Id and object of picList to the controller and it shows up null. I've looked at all the other SO solutions and changed my code to what they said and Im still getting null for both values in the controller.

So I've even tried to change the data that is being sent to the controller as such to see if that made any difference and it didn't.

in ajax call i changed the data to such

```
 data: {"Name": "Adam"},
```

and added this to the controller and still nothing is getting passed.

```
UnitImages(string Name,..
```

here is what the JSON.stringify(data) looks like.

[image]

View Model

```
 public class FileViewModel
 {
    public FileViewModel()
    {
        UnitPicturesList = new List<UnitPictures>();
    }

    public IList<IFormFile> Files { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int AuctionId { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public List<UnitPictures> UnitPicturesList { get; set; }
 }
```

model

```
public class UnitPictures
{
    public long ImageId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

controller

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UnitImages(long auctionId, List<UnitPictures> picList)
 { ...
 }
```

Ajax call

```
    function UpdateImages(auctionId, picList) {

    var data = { auctionId: auctionId, picList: picList };

    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
     
    $.ajax({
           cache: false, 
           contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
           dataType: "json", 
           type: "POST", 
           url: '/PhotoUploader/UnitImages',
           data: JSON.stringify(data), 
           success: function(data){ 
               if(data.Result == 1) { 
                   alert("images where successfully updated.");
               }else { 
                   alert('images where successfully updated.'); 
               }
           }, 
           error: function() { 
               alert("The images were not updated because of a problem.")
           }
   });
```

}

Comment: Is it possible you're exceeding some sort of file size limit?

Comment: I'm not uploading any files, just data about the files, like the file name or the order I want it displayed.

Comment: the model doesn't match that list... only imageid and sortorder are showing in your screenshot.  also check case... I think "ImageID" shows in screenshot, you have "ImageId" in the model.   (not sure if case will matter, though... I think it ignores for normal params...)

Answer (score 2):

Asp.net core MVC default binding value from form, Here you can try to add `[FromBody]` attribute on your parameter to change the resource to bind value from body.

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult UnitImages([FromBody]string Name)
 { ...
 }
```

Model details you can refer to [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-7.0).

Answer (score 0):

Try using a class that match the posted model. Something like this:

```
public class UnitPictures_ViewModel
{
    public int AuctionId {get;set;}
    public List<UnitPictures> PicList { get; set; }
    
}

public class UnitPictures
{
    public long ImageId { get; set; }
    public string FileName { get; set; }
    public string FileLocation { get; set; }
    public int SortOrder { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: added the ViewModel that I am currently using.

Comment: sorry no. Still not passing any results to the controller.

Comment: i saw your viewmodel, change the array propertyname to match posted model, or use the [JsonProperty""] attribute in class to match the property name